# JavaScript effect only works with 50% of the owl-carousel

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, owl-carousel

I have a owl-carousel with two diffrent click effects. The First one for everything over 736 px works fine but with my second effect there is something wrong.
At the moment there is just a div(#XXXXXX-handy) that shows but there is no way to remove it. The real problem is that it only works for 50% of the carousel. If I add more item, still works for 50%. If I remove some items, it still works for 50%.

Here is my JS:

```
else if (737 > screen.width) { 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".swisscom-item").click(function(){
            $("#swisscom-handy").show();
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".migros-item").click(function(){
            $("#migros-handy").show();
        });
    });
}
```

and here my HTML:

```
        <div class="owl-carousel kunden-carousel">

            <div class="kunden-item swisscom-item"><img class="kunde" src="img/swisscom.png"><div class="handybox" id="swisscom-handy"><h1>swisscom</h1><p>TEST1 TEST2 TEST3 TEST4</p></div></div>

            <div class="kunden-item migros-item"><img class="kunde" src="img/migros.png"><div class="handybox" id="migros-handy"><h1>migros</h1><p>TEST1 TEST2 TEST3 TEST4</p></div></div>
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2):

```
else if (737 > screen.width) { 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".swisscom-item").click(function(){
            $('.handybox').hide();
            $("#swisscom-handy").show();
        });

        $(".migros-item").click(function(){
            $('.handybox').hide();
            $("#migros-handy").show();
        });
    });
}
```